# Java Applet: Archive at HTML

Tags: java, applet

I'd like to run a Java Applet on my webpage, but - due to restrictions imposed by the web host - the only way I can access the JAR file containing the applet's classes is via an HTML link. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

An example of what I've tried to do:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="code" value="path.to.class.MyApplet.class" />
  <param name="archive" value="http://www.example.com/path/to/MyJar.jar" />
</object>
```

A fact potentially relevant to my problem: the applet class causes a JFrame to be displayed.

EDIT: I am using the most recent version of Chromium for Ubuntu, which, I assume, has HTML5 support. I have also tried doing this with the `<archive>` tag.

Comment: *"the applet class causes a JFrame to be displayed."*  Forget the applet.  Launch the frame directly from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: *"due to restrictions imposed by the web host"*  What web host specifically?

Comment: Wordpress (wordpress.com, not a custom deployment), because my budget is approximately $0 and my time is limited for the foreseeable future. When I eventually get the time and money I'd like to create and manage a website myself so I will not have these restrictions, but in the meantime I have to work within their framework.